# How to respond to other's compliment words like "you are doing a great job"

Tags: word-usage

For example, when a colleague says to me "You are doing great" ,Except "Thank you", I don't know what alternative expressions I can use to respond to other's compliments. I thought say a bit more than "thank you" might be more appropriate and I am wondering how native speaker would respond. Can any friend help me with that?

Comment: I don't think job-specific compliments need a special response that wouldn't also apply to other compliments. "Thanks" or "Cheers" is fine.

Comment: @nnnnnn Then what if the compliment is from friends or family memebers?

Comment: Something along the lines of "Thank you, I'm doing my best" or "Thank you, I'm trying hard" works. It indicates acceptance of the compliment but avoids the appearance of complacency or arrogance by suggesting that the greatness of the job can't be taken for granted, something could go wrong at any time!

Comment: I'm sure that this would be a better fit on 'Interpersonal Skills.SE'.

Comment: @BoldBen: Thank you Boldben! These expressions are exactly useful and are exactly what I want to express. I really appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a "Thank you" is not enough and the praise just keeps on coming it is common to add "You are very kind".

Comment: Piggybacking on @Elliot, "That is just too kind" or "I appreciate that! Thanks!"  are also appropriate

Comment: @Elliot Thank you so so mcuh I will use those expressions in future : )